# SERIALIZED CONTEXT data truncation issue [SPRING BATCH]

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, upgrade

Due to an upgrade of spring boot to spring boot 2.1.6, I encountred a spring batch exception on database :

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'SERIALIZED_CONTEXT' at row 1
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:955)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1094)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1345)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1027)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.
```

I dont won't to change the column directly on database, I look for a clean solution.  Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this exception ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont won't to change the column directly on database, I look for a clean solution. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this exception ?

Spring Batch does not prevent you from putting whatever you want in the execution context, but at the same time cannot force the database to accept more than what the column is defined to accept.

So the clean way to fix this is to modify the column in your DDL and set an appropriate value in [JobRepositoryFactoryBean#setMaxVarCharLength](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/JobRepositoryFactoryBean.html#setMaxVarCharLength-int-).

Comment: Thank you for the response. So, I think the only solution for now as you said is changing the column size to accept  the context value. And later I will try to implement a custom serialzer of context in order to reduce value size.

Comment: I've modfied the column and it works correctly. But, the second problem I am facing is that I use liquibase for updating database, this does not work for integration test because the liquibase scripts are executed before executing spring-batch meta-data schema and this trigger an sql error : Table BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT does not exist ! finally the tests passes as failed.

Comment: That's another issue, you need to make sure scripts are executed in the right order.

Comment: Yes it is another issue. However I will look how to resolve this.
Spring-batch scripts are included in core and executed automatically, I am not able change the order for integration tests. Liquibase scripts are first then spring-btach scripts.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58827480/can-you-initialize-spring-batch-metadata-tables-with-liquibase

Comment: Can we use VARCHAR2 for SERIALIZED_CONTEXT column? Because my company policy is not allowed CLOB columns so I can not create MetaData Tables with CLOB columns, is there any solutions for that situation?